# Targeting Iphone 4 orientations media queries

Tags: iphone, css, media-queries

How do I target the different iphone4 orientations using media queries?

I have the current setup but im not certain it works.

```
@media only screen 
and (max-device-height: 640px)
and (max-device-width: 960px)
and (min-device-width: 480px)
and (min-device-height: 480px)
```

and

```
@media only screen 
and (max-device-height: 960px)
and (max-device-width: 640px)
and (min-device-width: 480px)
and (min-device-height: 480px)
```

I would figure this out myself if i had an Iphone to test on but I don't.

Comment: You can use the http://iphone-emulator.org/ website. It will give you a good idea if it's working or not :)

Comment: Thanks for a great tip. All tough it don't seam to work at all.

Answer (score 0):

try this different,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-    scale=0.6667, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: How can this separate landscape and portrait css??

Comment: In our application that meta tag is working fine, and i didn't put CSS for portraits and landscape. I use liquid layout for that and it will working fine.

Comment: Ok the question is about media-queries though. the site im trying to polish dose not have a liquid design.